# How to customize a list of directories in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, lisp

I have a customizable variable, containing a list of directories. I would like to be able to customize it using some INS and DEL buttons in Emacs custom mode, and if possible even use a file picker for customizations. So what I have so far now is:

```
(defcustom my-system-include-paths '( "./include/" "/opt/local/include" "/usr/include" )
  "This is a list of include paths."
  :group 'mygroup
  )
```

I imagine that I have to use the `:type` parameter, but I don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Emacs is self documented, use it.

<kbd>M-:</kbd>`(info "(elisp) Composite Types")`<kbd>RET</kbd>

([online](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Composite-Types.html#Composite-Types))

e.g. you can define a list of directories like this:

```
(defcustom custom-directories nil
  "Custom variable"
  :type '(repeat directory))
```

Comment: I've already read quite some documentation today. I forgot about the alist concept, that was what I was looking for. Still an elisp newbie, thanks for the answer.